# Count number of post in a category

Tags: django, database, filter, count

I want to list all the categories in my news table plus add the number of post in each categories.
Here is my model :

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    titre_article = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    auteur_article = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_article = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modif_article = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categorie_article = models.ForeignKey('BlogCat',
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       default='1')
    contenu = RichTextField(null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre_article


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/blog/{self.id}"

class BlogCat(models.Model):
    nom_categorie = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom_categorie

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/blog/cat/{self.nom_categorie}"
```

From there I can't imagine what the code in the view.py should be.
Can someone help ?

Thx a lot :)

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate your `BlogCat` model with the number of `Blog`s:

```
from django.db.models import Count

BlogCat.objects.annotate(nblog=Count('blog'))
```

The `BlogCat` objects that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.nblog` that contains the number of related `Blog` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use cout()

```
obj = YourObject.objects.all().count()
```